# Does PyInstaller support installing dependent packages via pip on first use?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I am trying to use PyInstaller to distribute a Python app building with pywebview, tensorflow, etc. However, when I create a Python executable with PyInstaller, I find that the package is larger than my expectation. I am not sure if it just packs everything into installer which leads to the large package size.

So my question is, is it possbile for PyInstaller to pack only Python binary, and run `pip install` when it is run for the first time to reduce the size of distributed package?

I have tried using `pip` module like below:

```py
import sys, io
buffer = io.StringIO()
sys.stdout = sys.stderr = buffer

import pip
pip.main(['install', 'numpy'])

import webview
webview.create_window('Hello world', 'https://pywebview.flowrl.com/')
webview.start()
```

And when I run the built demo.exe I got error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "pip\__init__.py", line 13, in main
  File "pip\_internal\utils\entrypoints.py", line 43, in _wrapper
  File "pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 68, in main
  File "pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 114, in create_command
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.commands.install'
```

I don't have to stick to `pyinallter`, I would like to try any tool that supports to defer the dependency installation to the frist time running the program.

Comment: You could but you would have the pack the python executable with the `--add-data` option because pyinstaller does include one by default.

Comment: @Alexander I don't get it, can you elaborate a little more about `--add-data`. to me it's like just adding some data files to packages and I don't know how it will trigger `pip install`.

Comment: it wouldn't... you would have to program in that behaviour.

Comment: @Alexander Do you mean to call `os.system('pip install')` at the entrypoint for the first time?

Comment: well no, that wouldn't work unless pip was already installed on the users system in which case there would be no need to include the python executable.  What you are asking is possible but kind of unrealistic, especially if you are considering using the `--onefile` option... If that is your plan then I would say this idea of yours makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Alexander I don't have to use `--onefile`. It's OK for me to distributed the dist as a zip archive, or turn it in to `msi` in the future. I just want to defer the installeration of third party dependencies to the first time running the app.

Comment: Yes I am aware.  So that means that you would need to pack a python executable with the compiled application and write a script that would install all of the necessary libraries into the application directory before starting your main entrypoint.  It is not an easy task